# Asymptotic behavior of sum of regularly varying function

Tags: pr.probability, asymptotics

In the proof of Lemma 4.9 of [Beran et al (2013)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-35512-7), the authors consider a strictly stationary time series $X = \{X_t, t \in \mathbb{N} \}$ with regularly varying autocovariance function $\gamma_X(k) \sim L_\gamma(k)k^{2d - 1}$ where $d \in (0, 0.5)$.

They then compute

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(S_n) 
&= \text{Var}\Big(\sum_{t = 1}^n X_t\Big) \\
&= n \sum_{k = -(n - 1)}^{n - 1} \bigg(
1 - \frac{\vert k \vert}{n}
\bigg)  \gamma_X(k) 
\\
&\sim 
n \sum_{\stackrel{k = -(n - 1)}{k \neq 0}}^{n - 1} 
L_\gamma(k) \vert k \vert^{2d - 1} -
\sum_{\stackrel{k = -(n - 1)}{k \neq 0}}^{n - 1} 
L_\gamma(k) \vert k \vert^{2d}
\end{align*}
$$

What's the justification for the last step? This is probably a standard technique w.r.t. to regularly varying functions. But my literature review so far didn't yield a result. Is this supposed to be a form of Karamata's theorem?

I can't wrap my head around why it is okay to plug in the asymptotic behavior of the autocovariance function $\gamma_X$ **into the sum**.

Comment: I don't see any "plugging in of the asymptotic behavior" in what is written, just an algebraic identity in which somebody forgot to cancel $n$ in the second term. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Ahh sorry about that. This was a typo. The authors actually wrote $\gamma_X(k) \sim L_\gamma(k)k^{2d - 1}$ but I think this is also the solution. With regularly varying functions it doesn't matter if we write $\sim$ or $=$ because it can all be "included" in the slowly varying function, right? So instead of writing $\sim$ after plugging in $\gamma_X$ I could also write $=$ as well. Is that correct?

Comment: @AlbertRapp A regularly varying function $f$  can always be written as $f(x)=L(x)\cdot x^\gamma$ for some slowly varying function $L$ and some index $\gamma\neq 0$, so yes you can replace $"\sim"$ with $"="$.